# Vuetify vue.js ошибка в коде

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

При вставке `<div>ASD</div>`

Возникает ошибка: `error: The template root requires exactly one element`

```
<template>
    <div>ASD</div>
    <v-card>
        <v-tabs background-color="indigo" center-active dark>
            <v-tab v-bind:key="1" v-bind:href="'#clients'">Список клиентов</v-tab>
            <v-tab v-bind:key="2" v-bind:href="'#transactions'">История транзакций</v-tab>
            <v-tab-item v-bind:key="1" v-bind:value="'clients'">
                <v-data-table v-bind:headers="clients.headers" v-bind:items="clients.items"></v-data-table>
            </v-tab-item>
            <v-tab-item v-bind:key="2" v-bind:value="'transactions'">
                <v-data-table v-bind:headers="transactions.headers" v-bind:items="transactions.items"></v-data-table>
            </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            clients: {
                headers: [{
                    text: 'ID',
                    value: 'id'
                }, {
                    text: 'Наименование',
                    value: 'title'
                }, {
                    text: 'Рекламный бюджет',
                    value: 'amount'
                }, {
                    text: 'Дата создания',
                    value: 'created_at'
                }],
                items: [{
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'Test Name 3',
                    amount: '10000 RUB',
                    created_at: '3 дня назад'
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Test Name 2',
                    amount: '9900 RUB',
                    created_at: '5 дней назад'
                }, {
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Test Name 1',
                    amount: '17500 RUB',
                    created_at: '2 месяца назад'
                }]
            },
            transactions: {
                headers: [{
                    text: 'ID',
                    value: 'id'
                }, {
                    text: 'Сумма',
                    value: 'amount'
                }, {
                    text: 'Зачислено',
                    value: 'converted_amount'
                }, {
                    text: 'Комментарий',
                    value: 'comment'
                }, {
                    text: 'Дата транзакции',
                    value: 'created_at'
                }],
                items: [{
                    id: 3,
                    amount: '10000 KZT',
                    converted_amount: '2600 RUB',
                    comment: 'Пополнение рекламного бюджета для клиента: Test Name 3',
                    created_at: '3 дня назад'
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    amount: '100 USD',
                    converted_amount: '6900 RUB',
                    comment: 'Пополнение рекламного бюджета для клиента: Test Name 2',
                    created_at: '5 дней назад'
                }, {
                    id: 1,
                    amount: '5000 RUB',
                    converted_amount: '5000 RUB',
                    comment: 'Пополнение рекламного бюджета для клиента: Test Name 1',
                    created_at: '2 месяца назад'
                }]
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Vue должен быть **только** один корневой элемент. Вам ошибка прямым текстом это говорит. 
Оберните всё в тег `div` например

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>ASD</div>
        <v-card>
            <v-tabs background-color="indigo" center-active dark>
                <v-tab v-bind:key="1" v-bind:href="'#clients'">Список клиентов</v-tab>
                <v-tab v-bind:key="2" v-bind:href="'#transactions'">История транзакций</v-tab>
                <v-tab-item v-bind:key="1" v-bind:value="'clients'">
                    <v-data-table v-bind:headers="clients.headers" v-bind:items="clients.items"></v-data-table>
                </v-tab-item>
                <v-tab-item v-bind:key="2" v-bind:value="'transactions'">
                    <v-data-table v-bind:headers="transactions.headers" v-bind:items="transactions.items"></v-data-table>
                </v-tab-item>
            </v-tabs>
        </v-card>
    </div>
</template>
```